# What should our policy about images in questions be?

Tags: discussion, images

What should our policy on images be (In both questions and answers)? If we allow it, than what are the limit on the kind of Images given?

## Pros

- Posting Arabic as image looks nicer than posting it as text
- Can be used to explain the question further

## Cons

- Can be distracting or disturbing
- Images cannot be searched

Comment: you mean image of Arabic texts or generally any picture?

Answer (score 4):

I am for text.

I think searchability is important. Looking nice is good but not essential. Also everyone will likely to choose their own preferred images and can make reading less accessible.